# Header of my thesis

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I used the following for the header, as I have `\chapter*`. It works great, the only problem is with bibliography where the header shows as ''Chapter4. BIBLIOGRAPHY'' as chapter 4 is the last chapter.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

\fancyhf{} % clear the headers
\fancyhead[R]{%
   % We want italics
   \itshape
   % The chapter number only if it's greater than 0
   \ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \chaptername\ \thechapter. \fi
   % The chapter title
   \leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}

\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for the mock text

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

\kant

\mainmatter

\chapter*{Another introduction}
\chaptermark{Another introduction}

\kant

\chapter{Title}

\kant

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, Are you up for using a KOMA-class?

Comment: `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for the mock text
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\kant
\mainmatter
\addchap{Another introduction}
\kant
\chapter{Title}
\kant
\addchap{BIBIBIBIBIB}
\kant
\end{document}}
`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

Simply define a new style `bib`

```
\fancypagestyle{bib}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{%
   % We want italics
   \itshape
   % The chapter title
   Bibliography}
}
```

and issue

```
\pagestyle{bib}
```

just before your bibliography.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

\fancyhf{} % clear the headers
\fancyhead[R]{%
   % We want italics
   \itshape
   % The chapter number only if it's greater than 0
   \ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \chaptername\ \thechapter. \fi
   % The chapter title
   \leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{bib}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{%
   % We want italics
   \itshape
   % The chapter title
   Bibliography}
}

\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for the mock text

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

\kant

\mainmatter

\chapter*{Another introduction}
\chaptermark{Another introduction}

\kant

\chapter{Title}

\kant

\backmatter
\nocite{*}
\pagestyle{bib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

Some remarks:

- If your bibliography isn't in the `\backmatter` issue

  ```
  \clearpage
  ```

  before it.
- I've removed the `plain` page style:

  ```
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
  }
  ```

  since it doesn't changes the default one.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use the package `scrlayer-scrpage`:

```
\usepackage[markcase=noupper,headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\leftmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}% \cfoot* needs KOMA version 3.14 or newer
%\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}% with KOMA version 3.12 or 3.13
```

and define a new command `\unnumberedchaptermark` instead redefining `\chaptermark`

```
\newcommand*{\unnumberedchaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
```

To get the `\chaptername` in the header I redefine `\chaptermarkformat`

```
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\chaptername\ \thechapter. }
```

This works also if there is a table of contents, a list of figures or another starred chapter at the end of the document.

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[markcase=noupper,headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\leftmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}% \cfoot* needs KOMA version 3.14 or newer
%\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}% with KOMA version 3.12 or 3.13

\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\chaptername\ \thechapter. }
\newcommand*\unnumberedchaptermark[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for the mock text

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\kant

\mainmatter

\chapter*{Another introduction}
\unnumberedchaptermark{Another introduction}
\kant

\chapter{Title}
\kant

\chapter*{Summary}
\unnumberedchaptermark{Summary}
\kant

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```